# View latex translation of documentation when hovering on function definition

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docstring

I'm using vscode to write python code. I want to see the latex translation of the math in the documentation(of pytorch) when I hover on the function definition in [the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXeki.jpg) instead of a plain text.

Installing a couple of extensions and fiddling with the settings didn't help. Any solutions for this? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python extension does not support rendering mathjax. Please open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Comment: I had the same a made a feature request
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18959